# java code - merging arrays and sorting

Tags: java, arrays

**Homework alert**
Create a program that merges two arrays of non-negative (equal to or greater than 0) integers.

- Accept each array as input from the keyboard.
- You do not know ahead of time how many values will be entered, but you can assume each array will have a maximum length of 10,000 elements.
- To stop entering values enter a negative number.
- You may disregard any negative numbers input and not store these in the array.
- The elements of the two input arrays should be in increasing order. 
  In other words, each array element must have a value that is greater than or equal to the previous element value.
- An array may contain repeated elements.
- After the two arrays have been input, your program must check to make sure the elements of each array have been entered in order.
- If an out of order element is found, print the message `"ERROR: Array not in correct order"`

Your task is to merge the two input arrays into a new array, with all elements in order, lowest to highest.

Print out each of the original arrays entered, followed by the merged array. Please note that your program must output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers.

```
Sample Run 1:
Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit 3 3 5 6 8 9 -1
Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit 3 4 5 6 -5
First Array: 3 3 5 6 8 9
Second Array: 3 4 5 6
Merged Array: 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 8 9

Sample Run 2: Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit 4 5 7 2 -1
Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit 3 3 3 3 3 3 -100
First Array: 4 5 7 2
Second Array: 3 3 3 3 3 3
ERROR: Array not in correct order
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int a [] = new int[10000];
        int b [] = new int[10000];
        System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int print = 0;
        int print2 = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        while(count >= 0) {
            a[i] = scan.nextInt();
            if(a[i] < count)
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            count = a[i];
            if(a[i] >= 0){
                i++;
                print ++;
            }
        }
        while(count2 >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to             quit");
            b[c] = scan.nextInt();
            count2 = b[c];
            if(b[c] >= 0){
                c++;
                print2++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("First Array: \n");
        for(int j = 0;j < print;j++) {
            System.out.print(+a[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n\nSecond Array: \n");
        for(int h = 0;h < print2;h++) {
            System.out.print(+a[h]+" ");
        }
        if(flag == 1) {
            System.out.println("\n\nERROR: Array not in correct order");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("\n\n Merged Array: ");
            for(int j = 0;j < print;j++) {
                System.out.print(+a[j]+" ");
            }
            for(int h = 0;h < print2;h++) {
                System.out.print(+a[h]+" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I mainly don't get is

- how do i stop my code after one enters a negative number and then stop it from going into the array.
- Also, how would I sort the arrays and then merge the sorted.

Examples would be really helpful, I have been stressed out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific questions:

- you stop the program when the input (after removal of negative numbers) is empty
- use a stream to merge, sort and format in one line

To implement, you do not need to use arrays. Since only the behaviour may be specified (not the implementation), this may be implemented as follows:

- create a `List<Integer>` to hold *all* input
- read two Strings from input, for each String

  - split by spaces
  - parse each token to integer
  - ignore negatives
  - require that each number be not less than previous
  - add each number to the list
- sort the list
- print the list

This can all be achieved in a few lines of code.

The requirement to "end input with a negative number" is unnecessary - pressing Enter is enough (if you really want to test this, you can code it yourself).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    repeat:
    while (true) {
        System.out.format("Enter the first array");
        List<Integer> first = readList();
        if (first.isEmpty()) return;
        List<Integer> second = readList();
        if (second.isEmpty()) return;
        if (!isSorted(first) || !isSorted(second)) continue repeat;
        System.out.println("First array: " + first.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        System.out.println("Second array: " + second.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        System.out.println("Merged array " + Stream.of(first, second)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
    }
}

private static List<Input> readList(Scanner in) {
    return Arrays.stream(in.nextLine().split(" +"))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .filter(n -> n >= 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static boolean isSorted(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.equals(list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList())) return true;
    System.out.println("ERROR: Array not in correct order");
    return false;
}
```

<sub>**Disclaimer:** Code thumbed on iPhone - not compiled or tested</sub>

Since this is spoon feeding, I'll let you figure out how this works before you consider submitting it as you own work.

Comment: @Ali see edited answer for some code that should do it.